# Bluetooth connection between Universal app and medical device - UUID and CODFilter

Tags: bluetooth, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app, spp

I'm implementing an Universal app on both Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 platforms, which should connect with devices like [scale](http://www.andonline.com/medical/products/details.php?%20%20catname=&product_num=UC-351PBT-Ci) or blood pressure monitor by bluetooth technology. Unfortunatelly, I have difficulty in the discovering process and according to that I've no chance to pair and connect to the device.

I've found the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263144/bluetooth-spp-between-android-and-other-device-uuid-and-pin-questions) about this issue, but unfortunatelly it's associated with Android.

From the post above:

> **Describing the medical device:** The device is using Service Discovery
>   Protocol (SDP) and Serial Port Profile (SPP). It starts an inquiry
>   procedure to discover (up to 10) surrounding access points with
>   matched COD Filter and Service Name. Then it sequentially establishes
>   a connection (using Page Procedure) with the access point by checking
>   the PIN. Once the PIN is matched, the data is uploaded. Upon uploading
>   data the device waits for an acknowledge. The decice is the master and
>   initiates the communication.

I've also started from the [Microsoft Bluetooth Rfcomm Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Bluetooth-Rfcomm-Chat-afcee559).

**My questions:**

1. I'm dobious about my standard **UUID** number 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB. Is it appropriate in this circumstances?

   ```
   // The Id of the Service Name SDP attribute
   protected const UInt16 SdpServiceNameAttributeId = 0x100;

   // The SDP Type of the Service Name SDP attribute.
   // The first byte in the SDP Attribute encodes the SDP Attribute Type as follows :
   //    -  the Attribute Type size in the least significant 3 bits,
   //    -  the SDP Attribute Type value in the most significant 5 bits.
   protected const byte SdpServiceNameAttributeType = (4 << 3) | 5;

   public async Task Start()
   {
       try
       {
           if (rfcommProvider == null)
               rfcommProvider = await RfcommServiceProvider.CreateAsync(
                   RfcommServiceId.FromUuid(BluetoothServiceUuid));

           if (rfcommProvider != null)
           {
               if (socketListener != null)
               {
                   socketListener.Dispose();
                   socketListener = null;
               }

               // Create a listener for this service and start listening
               socketListener = new StreamSocketListener();
               socketListener.ConnectionReceived += OnConnectionReceived;

               await socketListener.BindServiceNameAsync(rfcommProvider.ServiceId.AsString(),
                   SocketProtectionLevel.BluetoothEncryptionAllowNullAuthentication);

               // Set the SDP attributes and start Bluetooth advertising
               DataWriter sdpWriter = new DataWriter();

               // Write the Service Name Attribute.
               sdpWriter.WriteByte(SdpServiceNameAttributeType);

               // The length of the UTF-8 encoded Service Name SDP Attribute.
               sdpWriter.WriteByte((byte)BluetoothServiceDisplayName.Length);

               // The UTF-8 encoded Service Name value.
               sdpWriter.UnicodeEncoding = Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;
               sdpWriter.WriteString(BluetoothServiceDisplayName);

               // Set the SDP Attribute on the RFCOMM Service Provider.
               if (rfcommProvider.SdpRawAttributes.ContainsKey(SdpServiceNameAttributeId))
                   rfcommProvider.SdpRawAttributes.Remove(SdpServiceNameAttributeId);
               rfcommProvider.SdpRawAttributes.Add(SdpServiceNameAttributeId, sdpWriter.DetachBuffer());
               // Start Bluetooth advertising
               //SetState(BluetoothServerState.Started);
               rfcommProvider.StartAdvertising(socketListener);
           }
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine( "ERROR: " + e.Message);
       }
   }
   ```
2. I'm not sure if there is a better method to set **Service Name**? Maybe I do this wrong? I think it's a main  problem.
3. What about **COD Filter** (in the specification there is a note that it should equals [00000000] for proper communication? Is there any method to set it using RfcommServiceProvider? Maybe I should also manually set PIN number or if it's required only in the pairing process?
4. I've noticed, in the microsoft samples - Server is only supported for the Windows platform. **It is possible to implement server functionality also for the WP?** - device which will receive data from the medical device should be a slave.

I've also read about Gatt protocol but it doesn't provide profiles for all devices which I need.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to solving my problem was to declare serial port connection in the app manifest file instead of declaring connection by specified UUID number:

```
<Capabilities>
    <DeviceCapability Name="proximity" />
    <m2:DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth.rfcomm">
      <m2:Device Id="any">
        <m2:Function Type="name:serialPort" />
      </m2:Device>
    </m2:DeviceCapability>
  </Capabilities>
```

And use **RfcommServiceId.SerialPort** as argument of RfcommServiceProvider.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a very similar boat; I'm trying to connect to a medical device using WinJS/HTML for an RT device, and I found this article to be very good:

http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/buildingapps/archive/2014/05/07/talking-to-robots-or-other-devices-using-bluetooth-from-a-windows-runtime-app.aspx

It looks like you're using c#, but you can get the idea from the javascript in the article.  Create a selector that looks for serial-type devices, then query for a list of all of those devices.  Here's some of the javascript from the article to illustrate the idea

var selector = Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Rfcomm.RfcommDeviceService.getDeviceSelector(     Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Rfcomm.RfcommServiceId.serialPort);

var devices = Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.findAllAsync(selector, null);

var device = devices[0];

return Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Rfcomm.RfcommDeviceService.fromIdAsync(device.id);

I'm still working on parsing the bytes that I get from the device, but using the above code, WinRT asks for a connection to the device, and my device begins to stream data, which has been the biggest hurdle.  Good luck!