# Problems with RFCOMM connection to device

Tags: c#, bluetooth, windows-phone-8.1, rfcomm

Everybody writes, that this method is possible:

```
   <DeviceCapability Name="proximity" />
    <m2:DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth.rfcomm">
      <m2:Device Id="any">
        <m2:Function Type="name:serialPort" />
      </m2:Device>
    </m2:DeviceCapability>
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn263090.aspx

[Connect to Bluetooth Device / how to set the rfcomm capability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27129649/connect-to-bluetooth-device-how-to-set-the-rfcomm-capability)

[Bluetooth connection between Universal app and medical device - UUID and CODFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24674084/bluetooth-connection-between-universal-app-and-medical-device-uuid-and-codfilt)

but my VS2013 writes: unknown namespace `m2`...
what is `m2`? how to include `m2`?

And writes `Capabilities` must contains `Capability`, not `DeviceCapability`.
I don't understand this error...

Comment: Can you provide  your markup for your app manifest?  The 2nd link you provided has a good example that should work. It has to go in the <Capabilities> tag, not the <Capability> tag.   What is your project type?  Windows Store? Phone 8.1? Phone Silverlight 8.1?

Comment: I solved this problem. I had SKD WP8 instead of WP8.1.
This method is available in WP8.1